# How can I check if the matrix is of the following form?

Tags: matrix

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 -a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & a & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -a & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & a & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -a & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & a \\
\end{array}
\right)$

That is, diagonal matrix with changing sign on the main diagonal.

Comment: Is "a" scalar or is it allowed to be another Matrix?

Comment: @JosephDoggie scalar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `u` is the matrix:

```
DiagonalMatrixQ[u] && AllTrue[Ratios@Diagonal@u, # === -1 &]
```

would return `True` for compliant matrices.

Comment: Just pointing out the obvious for OP in case it proves a later pitfall - if OP were unstatedly treating `a` as strictly positive, this solution will yield `True` when the first element is positive (unlike your example)

Comment: I checked with `u` and `-u` so both cases are covered. Only alternating signs are required. @AntiEarth

Comment: Yep, that's what I'm stating - OP may have had an unstated additional requirement that `a` is positive (why else start with `-a` instead of `a` in their example matrix?). In that scenario, your pattern matches their example matrices (first element negative) *but also* matches more (first element positive)

Comment: I can work with what's presented and stated. But this is an acute observation. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming that the matrix can be of any size, and that $a$ can stand for anything:

```
check[u_] := DiagonalMatrixQ[u] &&
             Apply[SameQ, Diagonal[u]*(-1)^Range[Length[u]]]

check @ {{-a,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
         { 0,  a,  0,  0,  0,  0},
         { 0,  0, -a,  0,  0,  0},
         { 0,  0,  0,  a,  0,  0},
         { 0,  0,  0,  0, -a,  0},
         { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  a}}
(*    True    *)

check @ {{-a,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0},
         { 0,  a,  0,  0,  0,  0},
         { 0,  0, -a,  0,  0,  0},
         { 0,  0,  0,  a,  0,  0},
         { 0,  0,  0,  0, -a,  0},
         { 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  b}}
(*    False    *)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mat = {{-a, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, a, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -a, 0, 0, 
   0}, {0, 0, 0, a, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, -a, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a}}

diag = Table[(-1)^n*a, {n, 1, Length@mat}]
(DiagonalMatrix[diag]) === mat

(* True *)
```